# Qt in separate thread gives :First-chance exception at 0x74f2c41f infoo .exe: 0x000006A6: The binding handle is invalid

Tags: c++, qt, runtime-error

i try to run QObject inhereted class called "Dispatcher" that is using  QtWebKit functions in separate thread.
then the main GUI thread , but when i init the object im getting :

```
First-chance exception at 0x74f2c41f infoo .exe: 0x000006A6: The binding handle is invalid
```

and the Signal and Slots in the object doesn't work , they do return true but never invoked.
i guess it related some how to the error i see . 
according to the internet i need to start the new thread like this :

```
CollectorWorker* pCollectorWorker = new CollectorWorker(pUrlStack,m_pSettings);
pCollectorWorker->moveToThread( QApplication::instance()->thread());
QCoreApplication::postEvent(pCollectorWorker, new QEvent( QEvent::User ) );
```

where CollectorWorker is the separate thread object that init the Dispatcher class.
when i init the Dispatcher class im getting this error.

### CollectorWorker.cpp

```
bool CollectorWorker::event( QEvent *ev )
{   
    if( ev->type() == QEvent::User )
    {
      Dispatcher dispatcher; // here im getting the error.
      return true;
    }
return false;
}
```

Comment: Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2006/01/04/509243.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`0x000006A6` stands for `RPC_S_INVALID_BINDING`

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2006/01/04/509243.aspx

> Explaining 'The Binding Handle Is Invalid'
>
> Today I want to try to give more insight into the 'Binding Handle Is
> Invalid' problem that a number of people have reported with the VS
> 2005 debugger.
>
> First, if all you care about is how to solve the problem: Enable the
> 'Terminal Services' service and reboot. If you want to know more, read
> on.
>
> The Terminal Services service
>
> I have seen many users say something
> like "I don't want to enable the Terminal Services service because
> it’s a security risk". While I certainly understand this fear, this
> stems from a misunderstanding of what the Terminal Services service
> provides.
>
> Enabling the Terminal Services service does NOT automatically enable
> Remote Desktop. If you want Remote Desktop disabled, then uncheck the
> remote desktop checkbox on the Remote tab of the properties dialog for
> My Computer. By default, Remote Desktop is disabled on Window XP, so
> unless you have gone and enabled it, it should already be disabled on
> your computer.
>
> So, why is this service enabled by default? The Terminal Services
> service is enabled by default because in addition to the Remote
> Desktop functionality, it also provides for Remote Assistance, Fast
> User Switching, process listing, DCOM support, and probably lots of
> other stuff that I don't know about because I don't work on the TS
> team. If you are running with the Terminal Services service disabled,
> then you are running in a strange and not recommended configuration.
> You also have a broken Task Manager, and probably a bunch of other
> things that directly or indirectly rely on this service.
>
> So please, regardless of what you want to do with Visual Studio, don't
> disable this service.

Comment: thanks for the replay , i did saw it , but i need to know how it related to my Qt app , and why i can't get single and slots working

Comment: Did read the link? It's about the error that you're getting, and how to fix it. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I have enabled terminal services and still getting this exception. In my case this exception can be safely ignored.